# How can I get multiple COUNTs from a single column with one query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

In an application I've written, I have lots of queries that it seems should be one...  but I can't figure out how to do it.

Here's a sample:

```
SELECT SUM(enrollment) AS SchoolEnrollment, COUNT(institutionID) AS NumberOfSchools
FROM Schools
WHERE LevelID IN (4,5,6,7,8,14,15,16,20)

SELECT SUM(enrollment) AS SchoolEnrollment, COUNT(institutionID) AS NumberOfSchools
FROM Schools
WHERE LevelID IN (10,11)
```

Then I have four additional queries that are identical, only differing in the LevelID's that are INcluded in the last line.  I'm basically getting a sum of enrollments and number of schools, based on the grade levels they offer.

Keep in mind that I not only need the results (I could simply UNION these queries), I need to know which number is which.

Thanks for any advice.

Russell Schutte

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM (case
                when LevelID IN (4,5,6,7,8,14,15,16,20) then enrollment
                else 0
            end) as firstEnrollmentCount,
       COUNT (case
                when LevelID IN (4,5,6,7,8,14,15,16,20) then 1
                else 0
            end) as firstNumberOfInstitutions,
       SUM (case 
                when LevelID IN (10, 11) then enrollment
                else 0
            end) as secondEnrollmentCount,

       COUNT (case
                when LevelID IN (10, 11) then 1
                else 0
            end) as secondNumberOfInstitutions,
FROM Schools
```

Or you could just use `GROUP BY LevelId` and then add up your results after you get the query back; it might be easier to work with, if that's an option:

```
SELECT LevelID, Count(*) FROM Schools GROUP BY LevelID
```

*EDIT* Replaced 1 with `enrollment` in the sum statement to better reflect the results gotten back by the original queries.

Comment: Thank you....  I had thought of the GROUP BY... but then I ran into trouble knowing my return values so that I could properly add up the (4,5,6,7,8,14,15,16,20) group, for example.  Is there a way to do that?

Comment: What do you mean knowing your return values? Using the group by, you have a column for LevelID and a column for the number of institutions for each LevelID. You could also have a third column for the total enrollment for that LevelID. Once you get that query back, you can just add together the rows that have the LevelIDs that you want to combine.

Comment: Thanks Gendolkari... I've been staring at this so long, I didn't think of simply adding the ColumnName (LevelID) back into the query - exactly as you showed it!  Thank you so much!